# C++: Passing polymorphic lambda to a function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I would like to pass a polymorphic lambda function which will perform certain operation (i.e. `==` or `<=` or `<` etc.) on different data types. So I would like to do operation like this:

```
bool func(bool (* f)(auto a, auto b))
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    float c = 3, d = 4;
    return f(a, b) || f(c, d);
}
```

to later execute it like this:

```
func([](auto a, auto b) -> bool { return a == b; });
func([](auto a, auto b) -> bool { return a <= b; });
func([](auto a, auto b) -> bool { return a < b; });
```

But unfortunately declaring a function pointer this way (with parameter of type `auto`) is not allowed. How should I do this properly?

Comment: Use a template, with an arbitrary functor rather than a pointer specifically.

Comment: @o11c That doesn't address the underlying problem.

Comment: @Sneftel: It handles the problem of being able to pass functions to other functions. And if `func` *genuinely* takes these conceptual `auto` parameters, then `func` is already a template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
template<class F>
bool func(F f)
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    float c = 3, d = 4;
    return f(a, b) || f(c, d);
}

int main()
{
    func([](auto a, auto b) -> bool { return a == b; });
    func([](auto a, auto b) -> bool { return a <= b; });
    func([](auto a, auto b) -> bool { return a < b; });
}
```

Comment: Ok, I like your solution much more than my own posted here as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without template `auto` keyword in argument of function doesn't have sense.
Either you make it as a template or provide specific type:

```
bool func(bool (* f)(int a, int b))
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    float c = 3, d = 4;
    return f(a, b) || f(c, d);
}

template<class T>
bool func2(T f)
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    float c = 3, d = 4;
    return f(a, b) || f(c, d);
}

…
func([](auto a, auto b) -> bool { return a <= b; });
func3([](auto a, auto b) -> bool { return a <= b; });
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/cbit5S26a5pyrULf

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found an answer. It is more strange that I would expect, but the `func` function must also be a lambda function like this:

```
auto func = [](auto f) -> bool
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    float c = 3, d = 4;
    return f(a, b) || f(c, d);
};
```